# Java IndexOutOfBoundsException Error reading math expression

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to read a math expression like 3+9-2*10/5 from JOptionPane and get its result -- taking into account order of operations, of course. I split up the string into just digits and just operands using String.split() and created a for loop that is looking for either multiplication signs or division signs -- in this case it is detecting the string "*" since it comes up first in the string.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String mathString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please type a simple math expression (i.e., without parentheses).");

    String[] parsedIntegers = mathString.split("\\D");
    String[] parsedOperands = mathString.split("\\d+");
    parsedOperands[0] = null;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parsedIntegers));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parsedOperands));

      for (int index = 1; index <= parsedOperands.length; index = index + 1)
      {

          if (parsedOperands[index].equals("*"))
           {
                 System.out.println("The multiplication sign is at index " + index + ".");
                 int multResult = Character.getNumericValue(parsedIntegers[index - 1].charAt(index - 1)) * Character.getNumericValue(parsedIntegers[index].charAt(index));
                 System.out.println(multResult);
           }
      }
}
```

The string array parsedOperands looks like this: [null, +, -, *, /].
The string array parsedIntegers looks like this: [3, 9, 2, 10, 5].

However, when I look for "*" which is at index 3 in parsedOperands and then try to multiply what is in (index - 1) and (index) in parsedIntegers, Java returns an IndexOutOfBoundsException. Why does this happen? Am I missing something?

Here is the error:

```
[3, 9, 2, 10, 5]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2

[null, +, -, *, /]

The multiplication sign is at index 3.
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at programmingpractice.SolveMathExpression.main(SolveMathExpression.java:49)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element in your array `parsedIntegers` is a single-character string, so when you use `charAt`, it should just be `charAt(0)`:

```
int multResult = Character.getNumericValue(parsedIntegers[index - 1].charAt(0)) *
                 Character.getNumericValue(parsedIntegers[index].charAt(0));
```

Using `charAt(index)` or `charAt(index - 1)` there tries to read past the end of the one-character string and throws the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` you got.

However, a more robust way to do this is probably to use `Integer.parseInt` so you can have multi-digit integers:

```
int multResult = Integer.parseInt(parsedIntegers[index - 1]) *
                 Integer.parseInt(parsedIntegers[index]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had overlooked the fact that String[index].charAt(index) was looking at location index, instead of at the first character .charAt(0) of the index of the string array I was pointing it to -- in this case String[index]. 

Instead of it being:

parsedIntegers[index-1].charAt(index-1) it should have been parsedIntegers[index-1].charAt(0). That's why it was giving me the index of out bounds exception.

Answer (score 2):

You should stop at one less than parsedOperands.length, hence you should use `<`, not `<=`:

```
for (int index = 1; index < parsedOperands.length; index = index + 1)
```

Btw, there is a special operator (++) for increasing a number by one. This code is shorter, but equivalent to the line above:

```
for (int index = 1; index < parsedOperands.length; index++)
```

Comment: It turned out that I also had an IndexOutOfBoundsException in the for loop, but I hadn't seen it because the first IndexOutOfBoundsException encounter was at the charAt().

Answer (score 1):

You are also considering index which is equal to the length of the array. i.e., your array length is 4 and your for-loop also checks for an element at index 4 because of your condition `( index <= parsedOperands.length;)`

```
  for (int index = 1; index <= parsedOperands.length; index = index + 1)
```

should be

```
  for (int index = 1; index <= parsedOperands.length-1; index = index + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

LE:

Your error is actually here:

```
int multResult = Character.getNumericValue(parsedIntegers[index - 1].charAt(index - 1)) * Character.getNumericValue(parsedIntegers[index].charAt(index));
```

You should use

```
int multResult = Integer.valueOf(parsedIntegers[index - 1]) * Integer.valueOf(parsedIntegers[index]);
```

This allows you to work with integers that have as many digits as possible.

But the rest remains.
Java arrays are 0 based.
Rewrite your `for` statement as follows:

`for (int index = 1; index < parsedOperands.length; index++)`

Actually the last part, `index++`, is just something that looks better (at least to me) because also your variant (`index = index + 1`) is ok.

Also see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for further information